# Can a Fully Connected Neural Network represent all Neural Networks of smaller size?

Tags: neural-networks, papers, math, deep-neural-networks

A fully connected Neural Network architecture can be characterized by a vector $\mathbf a = (a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_L)\in\mathbb N^{L+1}$ and an activation function $\sigma :\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. In this setting, $a_0$ is the input dimension and $a_L$ the output dimension of the network. $L$ represent its depth (the number of hidden layers) and $W:=\max_{1\le i\le L} a_i$ represents its width (the hidden layer with the highest number of neurons).
With that formalism, given a set of parameters $\boldsymbol\theta := \Big((A_l,b_l)\Big)_{l=1}^L \in \Big(\mathbb R^{a_1\times a_0}\times\mathbb R^{a_1}\Big)\times\cdots\times\Big(\mathbb R^{a_L\times a_{L-1}}\times\mathbb R^{a_L}\Big)$, the function realized by a neural network with architecture vector $\mathbf a$, activation function $\sigma$ and parameters $\boldsymbol \theta$ is given by
$$\mathcal F_{\boldsymbol\theta} : x\in\mathbb R^{a_0}\mapsto \mathcal A_{(A_L,b_L)}\circ\sigma\circ\cdots\circ\sigma\circ \mathcal{A}_{(A_1,b_1)}(x) $$
Where $\mathcal{A}_{(A_l,b_l)}(x):= A_l x + b_l$ and $\sigma$ is applied componentwise. This mathematical formulation of Fully Connected Neural Networks is taken from, e.g., [this paper by Berner et al. (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03062) (page 3).

My question is now the following : consider a neural network with architecture vector $\mathbf a$, depth $L$, width $W$ activation function $\sigma$ and *fixed* parametrization $\boldsymbol\theta$. For any other architecture vector $\mathbf a'$ with depth $L'\ge L$, number of neurons in each layer satisfying $a_l'\ge W\ \forall 1\le l\le L-1$ and activation function $\sigma$, is it possible to find a parametrization $\boldsymbol \theta'$ such that
$$ \mathcal F_{\boldsymbol\theta} (x)= \mathcal F_{\boldsymbol\theta'}(x)\ \ \forall x\in\mathbb R^{a_0 }\ ?$$

(of course, we need to assume $a_0' = a_0$ and $a_{L'}' = a_L$). In words, I am asking : **can Neural Networks with more computation units in each layer AND more hidden layers represent ALL neural networks with fewer computation units and hidden layers ?**

Intuitively, I am pretty sure that the answer is yes : for instance, if we don't increase the depth but only the number of neurons in each hidden layer, we can simply reproduce the smaller network with a properly chosen subset of the units, and set everything else to zero. The problem if we add more layers and do as I just said is that we now need to have the identity function from the $L$-th to $L'$-th layer, which is not feasible exactly for any reasonable activation function (I am mostly interested in ReLU, in which case a good approximation on a compact set is possible, but not an exact equality). Because deeper networks are more expressive, I would bet that the result still holds in that case.

I would appreciate an answer containing a proof and/or a reference (I am fine with adding more assumptions if needed). Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, you're really interested just in the case where all activation functions are equal (in both neural networks) and cannot be changed from layer to layer?

Comment: @nbro yes, exactly, the activation function is the same throughout all layers for both networks (it could be a ReLU activation for instance)